# How to change font for iOS app in Swift with dynamic size?

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uilabel

I'm trying to change the font throughout an iOS app in Swift. I'm currently using:

```
 var size:CGFloat = 16

 UILabel.appearance().font = UIFont(name: "Gudea", size: size)
```

Which changes every `UILabel` in my app to be the correct font. However, all labels are changed to size 16 despite different sizes assigned in the `Main.Storyboard`.

Is there a way to assign a font to every `UILabel` without changing the sizes assigned in `Main.Storyboard`?

or, perhaps,

Is there a better way to change the font used throughout the app?

Thanks!

Comment: The answer to your first question is no (unless maybe you write a script to run through the storyboard). I'd suggest creating some sort of global constant or `UIFont` category and start using that when you assign fonts programmatically.

Comment: @AdamPro13  that makes sense. perhaps the best solution is to simply use my current solution and override with an abstracted UIFont constant for headers and the like.

Comment: Yep, I tend to create a `UIFont` category & create class methods like `[UIFont standardGudea]`. This is also great when you have a bunch of colors that you use throughout your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to extend UIFont and set my labels programatically.

UIFontExtension.swift:

```
extension UIFont {

    class func myFontName() -> String { return "Gudea" }
    class func myBoldFontName() -> String { return "Gudea-Bold" }

    class func myNormalFont() -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name: UIFont.myFontName(), size: 12)!
    }

    class func mySmallBoldFont() -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name: UIFont.myBoldFontName(), size: 10)!
    }
}
```

MyViewController.swift:

```
myLabel.font = UIFont.myNormalFont()

mySmallLabel.font = UIFont.mySmallBoldFont()
```